# Prevent pam_mount unmounting if there are other active sessions?

Tags: mount, pam, automounting

I use `pam_mount` to decrypt (`gocryptfs`) and mount my home directory:

```
# /etc/pam.d/system-login excerpt
# ...
session [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_exec.so  quiet /usr/bin/mountpoint -q "/home/$PAM_USER"
session [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_succeed_if.so  service = systemd-user quiet
session    optional   pam_mount.so
# ...
```

```
<!-- /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml excerpt -->
<!-- ...defaults... -->

<!-- Encrypted home -->
<volume user="%(USER)" fstype="fuse" options="nodev,nosuid,quiet,nonempty,allow_other"
    path="/usr/bin/gocryptfs#/home/%(USER).cipher" mountpoint="/home/%(USER)"
/>

</pam_mount>
```

This works well for a single tty. The problem is if I open another, though my `pam_exec` line prevents it trying to re-mount, when I *exit* that second tty, it still unmounts. (Worse, it doesn't even unmount correctly, leaving 'transport endpoint is not connected', and I have to manually `fusermount -uz "$HOME"`. I tried adding `<fuseumount>fusermount -uz %(MNTPT)</fuseumount>` to the config, but no change.)

How can I prevent `pam_mount` from unmounting until the last session exits? (If tty1 that created the mount exited before tty2, I would want it to be kept mounted for tty2 even though it skipped mounting it itself.)

---

In fact, with `<debug enable="1" />` it logs:

```
May 03 15:19:39 hostname login[6607]: (pam_mount.c:441): pmvarrun says login count is 1
May 03 15:19:39 hostname login[6607]: (pam_mount.c:734): username seems to have other remaining open sessions
May 03 15:19:39 hostname login[6607]: (pam_mount.c:743): pam_mount execution complete
```

but then the next thing is everything complaining that 'transport endpoint is not connected', and sure enough I have no home dir in the first tty.

I've also noticed if I then `fusermount -uz $HOME`, it actually ends up *mounted*, as if `pam_mount` for the first login session (in which I manually unmount it to fix the error, expecting to have to manually mount it again) is automatically re-mounting it?

Comment: I think I might be hitting https://sourceforge.net/p/pam-mount/bugs/117/

Answer (score 0):

`pam_mount` has built-in detection of this and already tries to handle it appropriately. The problem seems to be a bug in the 'already mounted' detection that means it does not work for FUSE filesystems, or those mounted from a `server="..."`.

- Upstream bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/pam-mount/bugs/117/
- Debian bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/libpam-mount/+bug/1908638
- Arch bug report: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/70693
- Patch for the `server` case *only*: https://sourceforge.net/p/pam-mount/pam-mount/merge-requests/3/

---

I have it working with following [patch](https://sourceforge.net/u/ojford/pam-mount/ci/35273d68079348b6a73e0a14b25658434aeefc07/):

```
diff --git a/src/mount.c b/src/mount.c
index 75c0a39..781ccd0 100644
--- a/src/mount.c
+++ b/src/mount.c
@@ -127,10 +127,19 @@ static bool pmt_utabent_matches(const struct vol *vpt, struct libmnt_fs *fs)
    bool result = false;
 
    xcmp = fstype2_icase(vpt->type) ? strcasecmp : strcmp;
-   if (source != NULL)
-       result = xcmp(vpt->combopath, source) == 0;
+   if (source != NULL) {
+       if (strcmp(vpt->fstype, "fuse") != 0)
+           result = xcmp(vpt->combopath, source) == 0;
+       else {
+           size_t len_combopath = strlen(vpt->combopath);
+           size_t len_source = strlen(source);
+           result = xcmp(vpt->combopath + len_combopath - len_source, source) == 0;
+       }
+   }
+
    if (target != NULL)
        result &= strcmp(vpt->mountpoint, target) == 0;
+
    return result;
 }
```

applied and then:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ cp src/.libs/pam_mount.so /usr/lib/security/pam_mount_patched.so
```

and then with `pam_mount_patched.so` instead of `pam_mount.so` where applicable in my PAM configuration, for the time being. (Not overwriting the original just for ease of testing/reverting, and checking upstream's when a new version's available.)